# "Failed to instantiate java.util.List using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments "

Tags: java, api, spring-mvc, rest

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/allPatients")
    public List<Patient> getAllPatients() {
        return patientService.getAllPatients();
    }
```

Вызов данного контроллера выдает ошибку:

"Failed to instantiate java.util.List using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments "

ФЛОУ:

1) Вызов контролера:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/allPatients")
public List<Patient> getAllPatients(
) {
    return patientService.getAllPatients();
}
```

2) Реализация метода в сервисе:

```
@Override
public List<Patient> getAllPatients() {
    return patientRepository.findAll();
}
```

3) Сам нативный метод:

```
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface PatientRepository extends MongoRepository<Patient, String> {

    //Нативный метод
    List<Patient> findAll();
}
```

4) Предполагаемый результат вывода примерно такой:

```
[
    {
    "id": "198",
    "firstName": "Michael",
    "lastName": "Jackson",
    "age": 55,
    "credentialsId": "198",
    "cardNumber": "198",
    },
    .....
]
```

5) Вместо результата: "**Failed to instantiate java.util.List using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments ] with root cause**"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

6) Как выглядит коллекция Пациентов и коллекция докторов:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А какой код внутри `patientService.getAllPatients()`? Похоже, оттуда вываливается ошибка.

Comment: public List<Patient> getAllPatients() {
        return patientRepository.findAll();
    }...

findAll() - нативный метод Монго....
public interface PatientRepository extends MongoRepository<Patient, String> ...

Примечательно то, что вызов двух идентичных контроллеров для схожих сущностей не выдает никаких ошибок.

Comment: а какой стек-трейс у ошибки?

Comment: Похоже, что ошибка возникает при маппинге JSON, который возвращает mongo, в класс. Видимо, возвращается не лист/массив объектов Patient, а какой-то объект, содержащий в себе массив Patient. Можете привести, какой именно JSON возвращается при вызове такого метода?

Comment: Я думаю, тут более подробно разобрана похожая ситуация - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38539346/mongo-db-java-unwind-operation-in-aggregate-query-throwing-exception

Comment: @Sergi, думаю я прочла все статьи по этому поводу и все таки не получается исправить ошибку.. К тому же у меня нет аггрегации или элементарно $-метода в Query.

Comment: А можно ещё увидеть код `getAllPatients()` в классе `PatientServiceImpl`?

Comment: В своем первом комментарии я его указала:     public List<Patient> getAllPatients() {
        return patientRepository.findAll();
    }

Comment: На сколько я понимаю, у Вас возвращается объект (видимо доктор), который в себе содержит несколько полей + список пациентов. И вы пытаетесь этот объект представить как список пациентов --> ошибка. Скорее вам надо возвращать из репозитория объект Doctor и у него уже вызвать метод getPatients(), или переделать сам запрос (кстати, как сам запрос выглядит?)

Comment: Нет.. Необходимо вытаскивать всех докторов отдельно и всех пациентов отдельно. Доктор содержит в себе только часть пациентов. Метод findAll() нативный для Mongo, он прекрасно работает для докторов и для услуг, но не работает только для пациентов (причем он работал изначально). Проблема определенно именно в этом методе Mongo, вот только почему..

Comment: Здесь где-то есть фунция чата... Может так будет быстрее. Надо просто смотреть Ваш код и какой именно запрос у вас в MongoDB и что именно он возвращает

Comment: у меня не достаточно каких-то баллов для чата..Сейчас прикреплю скрины всего флоу

Comment: Еще пару вопросов - 1) У Вас сам класс Patient помечен аннотацией @Document? 2) Вы недавно не добавляли новых полей в класс или в объекты в базе данных? 3) А как выглядят объекты непосредственно в mongo (если можно, то лучше вывести всю коллекцию, из которой вы выбираете)?

Comment: (1) Аннотация присутствует. (2) Добавила поле <--@Field("serviceList") private
    List<Service> serviceList;--> (такое же есть и в классе доктора и при создании объекта, то бишь при регистрации, оно никак не задействовано и по умолчанию пустое). В коллекции пару новых юзеров. (3) Скриншот коллекции пациентов добавлю в описание

Comment: Моя последняя идея - удалить коллекцию полностью и создать заново.
Спасибо Вам @Sergi  за уделенное время ))

Comment: @Sergi, удаление коллекции и ее перезапись решили проблему. Видимо проблема была со стороны БД.

Comment: Да не за что) вполне возможно, что как-раз проблема была с serviceList..